# Create an TLS private key with bag attributes using openssl

Tags: openssl

I'm using openssl in generating an certificate requests ,

what option do I specify in generating an private key with bag attributes

Example:

```
Bag Attributes
    friendlyName: test-server
    localKeyID: 54 69 6D 65 20 31 34 37 34 34 32 31 35 37 30 35 35 39 
Key Attributes: <No Attributes>
```